# Taxonomy of a website and considerations

Tags: taxonomy

Please let me know is why taxonomy is important for website development?  What are the important considerations for taxonomy development?  Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use a taxonomy tree to categorize your content. Having your content organized makes it easier to find for visitors.

Depending on your site (size, content, subject) you may opt for a flat taxonomy: "News, Downloads, Support", or a tree, where each item has multiple sub-items for a finer granularity.

Tagging is also a great way to categorize content. It allows you to create a taxonomy tree on the fly, and add a piece content to multiple "tags" at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Ariejan, Is there some sort of tool to develop flat/tree structures?  Who would normally do taxonomy? And when it is done how it is actually put into place in the website? many thanks,

Comment: How you implement a taxonomy depends entirely on what tools you are using. Simply put: TaxonomyWord n-n Content. E.g. Content has many TaxonomyWords and a TaxonomyWord can have many pieces of Content. Then you can structure your TaxonomyWords separately in a list (e.g. give them a number to order them) or in a tree (tell which TaxonomyWord is their parent).

Answer (score 1):

A site taxonomy is also very important for Search Engine Optimization (SEO).  It allows spiders to understand the semantics of your site and provide the most relevant results to users in the search engine results page SERP).

With proper implementation, your taxonomy can drive your breadcrumnb navigation which also is important for SEO.

Understanding taxonomy is also about content governance and placing keywords on pages for a reason.